# grails generate-all coding explain

Tags: grails

Morning All,

I have a newbie question regarding grails. Many thanks in advance for helping me understand!

I don't understand the codes in the controller and the view generated by the generate-all command.

This is the save action in the book controller.

```
try {
            bookService.save(book)
} catch (ValidationException e) {
            respond book.errors, view:'create'
            return
}
```

I keep reading the guide over and over but I just don't understand their terms.  I don't know what **respond** is for now.  I assume **respond** POST the **errors** object inside **book** to the **create** view.

This is the codes in the create view.

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${this.book}">
   <ul class="errors" role="alert">
      <g:eachError bean="${this.book}" var="error">
         <li <g:if test="${error in org.springframework.validation.FieldError}">data-field-id="${error.field}"</g:if>><g:message error="${error}"/></li>
      </g:eachError>
   </ul>
</g:hasErrors>
```

So, ${this.book} should be NULL.  I don't see the view is looking for ${this.errors} to get the error message POST by the controller.  I don't get after the errors object is POST to the view, where ${error.field} is from.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured this out. The controller is binding the book.errors object to the create view.

```
respond book.errors, view:'create'
```

However, the view is not using the book.errors object to display the save error.

```
<g:eachError bean="${this.book}" var="error">
```

**${this.book}** is not **book.errors**.  I originally thought this.book is a pointer pointing to book.errors.  I was wrong.

**${this.book}** is the book object defined in the controller.  The view is not using the book.errors object at all.